# Macbook Pro upgrade advice

Tags: upgrade

I have a **MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)** and I'm told it's impossible to upgrade the RAM from the **8 GB 1867 MHz DDR3** that I have.

However, I recently learned I could upgrade the **256GB** harddrive I currently have. I'm thinking of upgrading to [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Transcend-480GB-JetDrive-820-PCIe/dp/B075H9QLJC/ref=asc_df_B075HBJPYF/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=310762440393&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=594452331524706394&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9044955&hvtargid=pla-404087214137&th=1).

However, will the SSD speed up my computer's performance as well as increase it's capacity OR will my expensive upgrade still leave me with a slow computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...will the SSD speed up my computers' performance as well as increase it's capacity OR will my expensive upgrade still leave me with a slow computer?

**The 2015 MacBook Pro came *with* an SSD, so the only thing you'll do is increase the storage capacity, not improve the performance.**

However, this sounds like you're just throwing parts at the problem in the hopes of solving it.   What you need to do is isolate and identify the problem causing the slowness:

- If your SSD is full, it could contribute to the performance issues.  In this case, adding a bigger SSD would benefit.
- Take a look at your Activity Monitor - memory and CPU.  See what's consuming either/both.<sup>*</sup>
- Try doing a clean install (wipe the drive and do a fresh install of macOS)

Make sure you have a Time Machine Backup.

---

<sup>*</sup> Whatever results you get from here, *search* this site prior to asking a new question because this topic has been asked/answered numerous times previously and you're likely to find your answer there.